# 2 Wheeled Vehicles (Physics in Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, unityscript, physics-engine

I'm trying to create a two wheeled vehicle in Unity3D, where the wheels are side by side (think a wheelchair or braitenberg vehicle). The intention is that if I drive one wheel, but not the other, the vehicle should turn. I should also be able to turn one wheel forwards and the other backwards and the vehicle should spin.

However, the vehicle generally just moves forwards (maybe with a slight bias in the direction I want to turn.. but only slight). I have a feeling I should change the drag/friction settings, but I have played with these with very little effect. Can anyone point me in the direction of what I should be doing to get this working right.

For info I am using the physics wheel colider built into unity 3D. I need to do this with physics so kinematic system would not be suitable.

Thanks

Comment: Wheelchairs tend to be four-wheeled :) Also note that you usually wouldn't turn just one of the wheels - you either fix the other wheel in place (e.g. prevent it from rotating), or you rotate it in the opposite direction. Otherwise it tends to turn very badly, of course - even tanks simply run one of the tracks in reverse when turning on a spot.

Comment: When one wheel is forced to rotate there are two possible outcomes - one, the other wheel also rotates at the same speed and the chair moves, or two, the other wheel remains stationary and the chair rotates around it.  Generally physics will follow the easiest path, so make the "wrong" path difficult (lock the other wheel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll add an answer here (although its my own question) as I have seen a couple of posts asking similar things. Even if you are creating a vehicle with 2 dominent wheels (like a little robot or a Britenberg vehicle) you should still add small wheels to the front or back for stability (think of them as casters). On these caster wheels, turn the stiffness factor for the forwards and sideways friction down to 0. On your main drive wheels, turn the sideways friction stiffness factor down to 0.5

This allows the vehicle to skid steer.

Comment: Or you can add a BoxCollider to body of your vehicle along with a Physics Mat with zero friction and zero bounce. and it will provide support and wont let your vehicle fall. while you try to move it with already added wheels. Hence you can create a vehicle with only 2 wheels :)